# volume buttons for Android headphones

Tags: android

I would like to know how volume buttons are connected to the trrs jack to control the volume of the phone as I am planning on doing a project that would require me to do this. I have searched this but can only find the on that uses a thumb wheel which I don't want. It must be buttons

So to sum up I want to know how to make earphones so that I can control the volume of the phone. Like the ones that come with the Samsung phone

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about inline buttons on a wired headset?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm talking about

Answer (score 2):

[image: Wiring ddiagram]

```
Button Impedance    Device Support  Function

R1 - 70 ohm or less     Required        [Function A]
R4 -  110 - 180 ohm     Required        [Function D]
R2 - 210 - 290 ohm      Required        [Function B]
R3 - 360 - 680 ohm      Required        [Function C]

Control Function    Description
Function A      Play/pause/hook (Short Press), Trigger Assist (Long Press), Next (Double Press)
Function B      Vol+
Function C      Vol-
Function D      Reserved (Nexus devices use this to launch Voice Assist)
```

See this link for complete details:

https://source.android.com/devices/accessories/headset/specification.html